# Parse multiple HTML to text and rename as parent Directory

Tags: bash, shell, bash-scripting

In a directory there are many folders .html inside, I would like all HTML parsed as new .txt with the name of the parent directory.

Example1/
Index.html>Example1.txt

Example2/
Index.html>Example2.txt

Comment: How would you like the tags removed?

Comment: Something like this works with individual files using sed,  cat file | sed 's/<b>.*</b>//g'

Comment: @z4nb0t it's [generally accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) that using regex to parse HTML will lead to elder gods from before the start of time awakening from their eternal slumber to consume your computer and all of humanity.

Comment: @evilsoup: Haha, that's a great one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously, you want to convert some HTML pages into plain text. Therefore I wouldn't strip the tags with a custom built solution (e.g. with some sed magic), but use a tool designed for that purpose like [html2text](https://github.com/aaronsw/html2text); from its webpage:

> html2text is a Python script that converts a page of HTML into clean,
>   easy-to-read plain ASCII text. Better yet, that ASCII also happens to
>   be valid Markdown (a text-to-HTML format).

To address your question of batch renaming:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' dirname
 do python path/to/html2text/html2text.py "${dirname}/index.html" > "${dirname}/${dirname}.txt"
done
```

Here the find command lists all directories only located in the current directory (i.e. not recursive) and the read command (in the while condition) assigns the values to the variable `$dirname`. Finally, the command(s) between `do` and `done` get(s) executed, here it converts the files according to your request. As pointed out by @slhck you need to use such a complex command, so that dirnames with whitespaces won't break anything.

**[Edit]**: Another variant to convert all HTML files under the current directory:

```
find . -iname "*.html" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' filename
  do python path/to/html2text/html2text.py "${filename}" > "${filename%.*}.txt"
done
```

`iname` searches case **i**nsensitive for `*.html`.

`${filename%.*}.txt` strips the extention and appends `.txt`, i.e. if `filename` is `some/path/index.html`, `${filename%.*}` is `some/path/index` and finally `${filename%.*}.txt` is `some/path/index.txt`.

---

When you use the *Z shell*, you can use a much cleaner for loop, without braking at white spaces:

```
for i (*(/)) python path/to/html2text/html2text.py "${i}/index.html" > "${i}/${i}.txt"
```

The trick here is that `*(/)` does filename generation, but only returns directories `(/)`.

**[Edit]**: Also in zsh syntax the variant to convert all HTML files under the current directory (you need the option `EXTENDEDGLOB` to be set):

```
for i ((#i)**/*.html) {
   python path/to/html2text/html2text.py "$i" > "${i:r}.txt"
}
```

`(#i)` uses case **i**nsensitive globbing, `**` searches recursively, hence returning all HTML files under the current working directory. (If symbolic links should be followed, use three stars `***` instead of two).

If you have more than one command inside the for loop, use curly `{ ... }`brackets (unnecessary here, but they won't hurt).

`${i:r}` strips the extention (r for remove) from the variable `$i`.

Comment: @z4nb0t: Sorry, I forgot the redirection `>` in my first version. Now it should work as stated. (The error was, that html2text expects as an optional second parameter the encoding of the HTML page, but got the name of the txt file).

Comment: i just noticed some folders have multiple html files, is this going to be a problem?

Comment: @z4nb0t: It's no problem, the command given does exactly what you asked for and takes only index.html in every folder. It's easy to use a second for loop to loop also over all html files in the dirs. But you need to specify how the renaming should be done then.

Comment: ok, the renaming part worked but it made the output blank files, not sure what is wrong

Comment: @z4nb0t: html2text workes fine for me, can you provide an example HTML file which is not working for you? Don't know if it matters, what python version do you use?

Comment: python 2.6 here is a paste of the output: http://pastebin.com/4Hxnq4Nw

Comment: Can you please upload the _input_ html file to pastebin, too?

Comment: here is an example of one html file i am trying to parse http://pastebin.com/tptzvT1Y

Comment: This breaks when file names or paths contain whitespace. You should use the exec option of find or pipe its output into a while loop (but only with the `-print0` option. See: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: @slhck: Thanks and of course you are right, I tried my best to improve the command -- and that is exactly why I really prefer `zsh` over other shells, because you simply don't need `find` for such simple tasks. `:)`

Comment: @z4nb0t: This is what I get out of you example HTML file using Python 2.7.3: http://pastebin.com/8ugyTGmh -- looks fine.

Comment: yes i use zsh, but im not very good with it yet. i will update python and try it on a single file first

Comment: @z4nb0t: zsh is very powerful, but of course you need some training time. If you are interested, I really recommend http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide.pdf by Peter Stephenson, the current maintainer of zsh. Don't get frightened by its size, IMHO it is easy to read (at least the first chapters ;)

Comment: thanks allot for your recommendation and that command works perfectly but can we tweak it to take the input all *html instead of index.html now? i just realized this is more ideal for my purpose.

Comment: @z4nb0t: Edited my answer for both bash and zsh syntax.

Comment: i tried with and without bracket but it returns zsh: no matches found: (#i)**/*.html

Comment: @z4nb0t: Sorry again! I forgot, that you need the option EXTENDEDGLOB to be set. Use `setopt extendedglob` (and best put it into your `~.zshrc`). Corrected my answer.