# How to rename multiple files in bash (not by pattern, but prompting for each new name)?

Tags: linux, bash, rename

I want to rename all files in a directory. The new names don't follow any pattern, so I can't use `rename`.
Is there any efficient way to do this, so I won't have to use `mv foo.txt bar.txt` for every single file?

Comment: If the new names do not follow **any** pattern the only thing you can do is list the directory contents to a file and then edit the file to suit.

Comment: You could write your own BASH script to ask for a new name for each file

Comment: By sheer luck I discovered `imv` (from renameutils) which allows you to interactively rename a file. But that will only accept one file, so you need a loop: `for file in *; do imv "$file"; done`.

Comment: Thanks Bobby, that's exactly what I've been looking for. Could you post it as an answer, please, so I can upvote you properly?

Comment: Pinging @Bobby (n.st, you need to explicitly @-mention users in order for them to receive a notification.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When thinking about writing this as a script I checked if possible names are already taken, and turns out my guess "interactive move" is already written and ready to use. For most systems it should be available in the [renameutils-package](http://www.nongnu.org/renameutils/), which contains various tools which are very helpful:

- **qmv/qcp**: Quick Move/Copy, writes all filenames to a text file which then can be edited.
- **imv/icp**: Interactive Move/Copy, asks for the new name of the files.

The problem with `imv`/`icp` in this case is, that those only accept one argument:

```
imv FILENAME
```

Multiple arguments will yield an error. So you'll basically have to wrap it up in a short `for` loop:

```
for file in *; do imv "$file"; done
```

That is of course hard to type, so we should wrap this into a ready to use function which we can place in our `.bashrc` file.

```
# Mass Interactive Move
function mimv {
    for file in "$*"; do
        imv "$file"
    done
}
```

Fortunately, `imv` shows the name of the file which is currently process, so we don't need any echo statement in there so that we know what is going on.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this command:

```
for i in *; do
   read -p "$i -> " newname
   if [[ ! -z "$newname" ]]; then
      mv -v -- "$i" "$newname"
   fi
done
```

It will prompt you for a new name for every file and also for every directory (`for i in *`) in the current directory. The new name gets read into `$newname`. If you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> without typing in a new name, nothing is done (`-z $newname` checks, if `$newname`is empty (**z**ero); `!` is logical `not`), otherwise `mv` is used to rename the file.

---

If you want to change the file name only a little bit, it's more efficient if you can *edit* it, starting with the old file name, as suggested by @grawity:

```
for i in *; do
   read -p "$i -> " -e -i "$i" newname
   if [[ ! -z "$newname" ]]; then
      mv -v -- "$i" "$newname"
   fi
done
```

---

*I tested it with filenames containing spaces and braces, however please use it on your own risk (and make a backup of the original files before).*

Comment: Heh, you were faster. And you did test with spaces in the names, which I forgot.

Comment: If you use `read -p "$i -> " -e -i "$i" newname`, it'll let you edit the old name directly.

Comment: @Hennes: I was trained by a comment by slhck (http://superuser.com/questions/593396/parse-multiple-html-to-text-and-rename-as-parent-directory/593401#comment729168_593401) earlier that day `;)`

Comment: @grawity: Thanks, that's a neat trick -- I incorporated it into my answer.

Comment: @mpy: except you didn't, `-e -i "$i"` is the key part :D

Comment: @grawity: Yes and no `;)` I used only the `-p` option in my old answer, and made a second variant with your complete suggestion, because IMHO in some cases it will be better to start the new filename from scratch.

Comment: Sorry about that nitpicking there—I do hope you took it as constructive :) I'm just very concerned about "broken" Bash (or similar) scripts that you can see all over the web. Most of these could easily be rewritten to work safely, and I think Super User would be the best place to promote that.

Comment: @slhck: I really appreciated your comment and you see, I learned from it `;)` as I'm with you that the scripts/snippets on SU should be as bullet proof as possible. However in everyday's fights with the command line I try to save every keystroke... the less keystrokes the more elegant `:)`

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for files in $( echo * );
do
     echo -n Rename $files  to which name? ;
     read new_name ;
     mv "$files" "$new_name";
done
```

Comment: `for files in $(echo *)` is very redundant – it could be replaced with `for files in *`, which even works properly with spaces in names.

Comment: Aye. i used it in an earlier version. One which asked for a pattern of files so you could just use ./q testfile to rename all files matching testfile*. I cut those parts out before posting. (It  was not as nice as mpy's answer is atm, but I do like to add small things such as if [ -z $1 ] ; then
  echo Usage: $0 files to rename
  exit
fi

Comment: `if [ -z "$1" ]`